# Wordpress loop: custom number of posts and sort by date

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, date, categories

I have tried to find a solution to something I need on the website (example here: https://www.baiweb.nl/). I have been looking for a way to show a custom number of posts per category AND sort them by date. I have managed to get a single post per category, but I can't seem to fix the rest. It sorts the posts itself by date now, but not all of them.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to sort this loop, with all different categories, by date?
2. Is it possible to control the number of posts shown per category? This one is extra for me, not essential, but it would be nice.

Hope someone can help! Thanks a lot in advance for your time!

Here is my code used in the loop now:

```
    <?php 

    $categories = get_categories();
    $cats = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cats[] = $category->name . ", ";
    }

    $exclude_posts = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
    // build query argument
    $query_args = array(
            'category_name' => $cat,
            'showposts' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    // exclude post that already have been fetched
    // this would be useful if multiple category is assigned for same post
    if( !empty($exclude_posts) )
        $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_posts;

    // do query
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // check if query have any post
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        // start loop
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            // set post global
            $query->the_post();

            // add current post id to exclusion array
            $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();

            ?>
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('loop');?>>

                                <div class="corner"><span><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ echo $category->name.'<br> '; } ?></span></div>

                                <!-- thumbnail -->
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="image">
                                <?php 
                                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'medium', true);
                                    if ( in_category('2') || in_category('32') ) {
                                        echo '<div class="newstitle">' . the_title() . '</div>';
                                    } 

                                    else {
                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                            echo "<div class='ctr-image test2' style='background-image: url(" . $thumb_url[0] . ")'></div>";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo '<div class="newstitle">' . the_title() . '</div>';
                                        } 
                                    } 
                                ?>          
                            </a>        

                            <div class="content">
                                <span class="date"><?php the_time('j/m/Y'); ?></span>
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( in_category('2') || in_category('32')  ) {} 
                                            else {  echo the_title();} ?>           
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>  
            <?php
            
            // do something
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Your categories `foreach` loop has to englobe everything. Then we do a simple loop but we specify what arguments to use depending on each categories.

Here is our final result.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories(); // ... get all our categories
foreach( $categories as $category ) { // ... start foreach categories
  if ( $category->name == 'Mercury' ) { // ... if our category name is 'Mercury'
    $posts_per_page = 1; // ... 1 post per page if our category is named 'Mercury'
  } else { // ... else, for all other categories
    $posts_per_page = 3; // ... 3 posts per page
  };
  $args = array( // ... all our arguments
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, // ... 1 or 3 posts per page depending on our categories
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $category->name,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date', // ... order by date
    'order' => 'ASC', // ... most recent first 
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // .. start a new loop
  if( $query->have_posts() ):
    echo '<section>';
    echo '<h1>' . $category->name . '</h1>'; // ... only display our section IF a post exist in the category
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
      echo '<article>'; // ... our post template
      the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' );
      echo '</article>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</section>';
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata(); // ... After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query. 
};  // ... end foreach categories
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your quick and comprehensive answer! The part of the number of categories is working very well, however, the outcome is slightly different than I want. It may be that my question was not clear, apologies for that.

What you have already made beautiful is all the categories with posts that belong to it. What I want to achieve is that all messages are mixed up, sorted by date and, what was already done here, I can indicate how many posts are in per category. Is that even possible?

Some screenshotsof the outcome of your code:
[image]

This is what I am trying, except now I need to sort this by date:
[image]

This is the code slightly adjusted:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories(); // ... get all our categories
foreach( $categories as $category ) { // ... start foreach categories
    if ( $category->name == 'Mercury' ) { // ... if our category name is 'Mercury'
        $posts_per_page = 1; // ... 1 post per page if our category is named 'Mercury'
    } else { // ... else, for all other categories
        $posts_per_page = 2; // ... 3 posts per page
    };
    $args = array( // ... all our arguments
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, // ... 1 or 3 posts per page depending on our categories
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => $category->name,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date', // ... order by date
        'order' => 'ASC', // ... most recent first 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // .. start a new loop
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        // echo '<section>';
        // echo '<h1>' . $category->name . '</h1>'; // ... only display our section IF a post exist in the category
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
            echo '<article>'; // ... our post template
            echo '<h1>' . $category->name . '</h1>';
            the_time('j/m/Y');
            the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' );
            echo '</article>';
        endwhile;
        // echo '</section>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // ... After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query. 
};  // ... end foreach categories ?>
```

Hope this is clear, thanks again!